# Difference between columns in different rows?

Tags: sql, window-functions, hana

I have a table with the below structure

```
ID - Task  | Performed BY | Start Date | End Date  
1 --- Task 3 --- John --------- 9/16/2017 - 9/17/2017  
1 --- Task 2 --- Jim  ----------- 9/14/2017 - 9/16/2017  
1 --- Task 1 --- John  --------- 9/10/2107 - 9/13/2017  
2 --- Task 2 --- Jane --------- 9/14/2017 - 9/15/2017  
2 --- Task 1 --- Claire -------- 9/12/2017 - 9/13/2017
```

I need to create a new column that shows the total time (duration) taken to perform all the tasks for each ID in SAP HANA. That is End Date of the last task minus the start date of the first task for each ID.

Below is the result that I need:

```
ID - Task  | Performed BY | Start Date | End Date | Duration  
1 --- Task 3 --- John --------- 9/16/2017 - 9/17/2017 -- 7 Days  
1 --- Task 2 --- Jim  ----------- 9/14/2017 - 9/16/2017 -- 7 Days  
1 --- Task 1 --- John  --------- 9/10/2107 - 9/13/2017 -- 7 Days  
2 --- Task 2 --- Jane --------- 9/14/2017 - 9/15/2017 -- 3 Days  
2 --- Task 1 --- Claire -------- 9/12/2017 - 9/13/2017 -- 3 Days
```

This can be done in SQL using the following query:

SELECT
    ID, Task, Performed By, Start Date, End Date,
        DATEDIFF(day,
                 MIN(Start Date) OVER (PARTITION BY ID),
                 MAX(End Date) OVER (PARTITION BY ID)) Duration
FROM Table;

I need to use SAP HANA to perform this task. Any help on how I could migrate this SQL query to HANA is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAP HANA supports standard SQL [window functions](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.03/en-US/20a353327519101495dfd0a87060a0d3.html) and also provides a date calculation function [`days_between`](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.03/en-US/20e16ca5751910148da4fc7ec69bae03.html).
You can write the code like this:

```
SELECT "ID", "Task", "Performed By", "Start Date", "End Date"
     , DAYS_BETWEEN(MIN("Start Date") OVER (PARTITION BY "ID"),
                   MAX("End Date") OVER (PARTITION BY "ID")) "Duration"
FROM tasks
order by "ID", "Task";

ID  Task    Performed By    Start Date  End Date    Duration
1   Task 1  John            10/09/2017  13/09/2017  7       
1   Task 2  Jim             14/09/2017  16/09/2017  7       
1   Task 3  John            16/09/2017  17/09/2017  7       
2   Task 1  Claire          12/09/2017  13/09/2017  3       
2   Task 2  Jane            14/09/2017  15/09/2017  3
```